# ZeroMQ: why a Client Server program without a use of multiprocessing fails?

Tags: python-2.7, multiprocessing, client-server, zeromq

I recently encountered ZeroMQ ( `pyzmq` ) and I found this very useful piece of code on a website [Client Server with REQ and REP](http://learning-0mq-with-pyzmq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyzmq/multiprocess/multiprocess.html) and I modified it to make only a single process call. My code is:

```
import zmq
import sys
from multiprocessing import Process

port = 5556

def server():
    context = zmq.Context()
    socket = context.socket(zmq.REP)
    socket.bind("tcp://*:%s" % port)
    print "Running server on port: %s" % port
    # serves only 5 request and dies
    #for reqnum in range(4):
        # Wait for next request from client
    message = socket.recv()
    print "Received request : %s from client" % message
    socket.send("ACK from %s" % port)

def client():
    context = zmq.Context()
    socket = context.socket(zmq.REQ)
    #for port in ports:
    socket.connect ("tcp://localhost:%s" % port)
    #for request in range(20):
    print "client Sending request to server"
    socket.send ("Hello")
    message = socket.recv()
    print "Received ACK from server""[", message, "]"
    time.sleep (1) 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Process(target=server, args=()).start()

    Process(target=client, args=()).start()

    time.sleep(1)
```

I realise that ZeroMQ is powerful, especially with `multiprocessing`/Multi-threading calls, but I was wondering if it is possible to call the `server` and `client` methods without calling them as a `Process` in `__main__`. For example, I tried calling them like:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    server()
    client()
```

For some reason the `server` started but not the `client` and I had to hard exit the program.
Is there any way to achieve this without `Process` calling? If not, then is there a `socket` program ( with or without a client server type architecture ) that functions exactly like the one above? ( I want a single program, not 2 programs running in different terminals as a classic CL-SE program ).

Using Ubuntu 14.04, 32-bit VM with Python-2.7

Answer (score 1):

### Simply, the `server()` processing *had* to start, *not* the `client()`

Why?

because the pure **`[SERIAL]`**-process scheduling has stepped into the `server()` code, where a `Context` instance has been instantiated, a `Socket`-instance was created, and next, the call to a **`socket.recv()`** method has hung-up the whole process into an unlimited & uncontrollable waiting state, expecting to receive some message, having the **`REP`**-LY Formal Behaviour Pattern ready on the local-side, but having no live counterparty, that would have sent any such expected message yet.

Yes, distributed-computing has several new dimensions ( degrees-of-freedom ) to care about -- the elementary (non)-presence and order of events being just recognised in this trivial scenario.

Wherever I can advocate, I do, NEVER use a blocking format of **`.recv()`** + [read about a **risk of a principally un-salvageable** **`REQ/REP`** mutual **dead-lock**](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3A3666197%20%5Bzeromq%5D%20is%3Aanswer%20dead-lock) ( you have no doubt when it will happen, but have a certainty, it will & a certainty, you cannot salvage the mutually dead-locked counterparties, once it happens )

### So, welcome into the realms of a distributed-processing reality

Comment: Thanks for the descriptive answer. Although I managed to understand most of what you have written, I still have an unanswered question: is there a `socket` program (with or without a client server type architecture) that functions similarly to the one above? - And I need a single program, not 2 programs.

Comment: Oh, sure it is. Just use always the non-blocking form of the `.recv( ... )` and adapt the algorithmisation to either use a `Poller.poll( .. )` to test a presence of a message. The single program shall launch properly `def`-ed `client()` and `server()` using either a `multiprocessing` or `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor()`, so the whole circus happens inside your single `python`-interpreter terminal window, as indicated above. There was nothing left un-answered. The reason why the original code was blocked was explained right in the front of the original answer. Modify the code & it runs